# Why won't my CSS elements center?

Tags: html, css, jsfiddle

I am trying to have my child elements be vertically centered on their parent elements.  Something is wrong with my css code but I can't tell what it is:

css:

```
#parent_div_1, #parent_div_2, #parent_div_3{
    width:90%;
    height:20%;
    margin-right:10px;
    border:2px solid #a1a1a1;
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 5%;
    padding-top: 5%;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
    background:#dddddd;
    border-radius:25px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin:4px;
}
.child_div_1{
    float:left;
    margin-right:5px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border:2px solid #a1a1a1;
    background:#dddddd;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

html:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<div id='parent_div_1'>
<div class ='child_div_1'>asd</div>
<div class ='child_div_1'>asd</div>
</div>

<div id='parent_div_2'>
<div class ='child_div_1'>asd</div>
<div class ='child_div_1'>asd</div>
</div>

<div id='parent_div_3'>
<div class ='child_div_1'>asd</div>
<div class ='child_div_1'>asd</div>
</div>
```

link to my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wasingej/Y4FA5/

Comment: `vertical-align` only applies to inline-level and table-cell elements. See for example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick solution is to set

`display: table;` for #parent_div_1, #parent_div_2, #parent_div_3

and

`display: table-cell;` for .child_div_1

Answer (score 0):

Add display: inline-block to the parent div style.

```
#parent_div_1, #parent_div_2, #parent_div_3{
    ...
    vertical-align:middle;
    display: inline-block;
    ...
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9Y7Cm/5/

Answer (score 0):

Add `Display:inline-block;` to your css on `#parent_div_1, #parent_div_2, #parent_div_3`:

**CSS**

```
#parent_div_1, #parent_div_2, #parent_div_3{
    width:90%;
    height:20%;
    margin-right:10px;
    border:2px solid #a1a1a1;
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 5%;
    padding-top: 5%;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
    background:#dddddd;
    border-radius:25px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin:4px;
    display:inline-block; /* ADDED CSS */
}
.child_div_1{
    float:left;
    margin-right:5px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border:2px solid #a1a1a1;
    background:#dddddd;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

DEMO HERE: http://jsfiddle.net/Y4FA5/21/

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
body{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
    margin:0px auto;
}
#main{
    position: relative;
width:500px;
height:500px;
}
#abc{
text-align:center;
background-color:#0F0;
height:250px;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

#abc span {
    vertical-align:middle;
    display: table-cell;
}
</style>
<div id="main">
    <div id="abc">
     <span>asdfasdfafasdfasdf<br/> sdfjdsl flkjdsflk sjdflkjdsf </span>    
    </div>

</div>
```